# Bash script creates zombie and uses 100% CPU

Tags: linux, bash, sh, zombie-process

I have a bash script which runs in a loop. Occasionally, the script gets into a state where it is using 100% of the CPU. Looking at pidtree, when that happens, the process has launched a child process to call `date`.

```sh
my_script(401)---my_script(463)---date(15804)
```

That PID of that child process is never changing. Moreover, that child process is somehow a zombie.

```
1 R root       463   401 51  80   0 -  4997 -      Mar22 ?        6-17:43:01 /bin/bash -eu /usr/sbin/my_script
0 Z root     15804   463  0  80   0 -     0 -      Mar28 ?        00:00:00 [date] <defunct>
```

Luckily, my code has exactly one place where `date` is called. That line, in a simplified version of the script, looks like **(updated to include flock)**

```sh
LOG="/tmp/foo"
(
flock -e -n 200 || exit 1
while true; do
  do_something_that_includes_sleep
  vals=("$(date --iso-8601=seconds --utc)")
  echo ${vals} >> ${LOG}
done
) 200>>${LOG}
```

How can this possibly cause `date` to become a Zombie? Even if it did somehow become a zombie, why would the main script be in Running state consuming 100% of CPU instead of blocking on a pipe read from the child?

Comment: Did you just happen to catch the zombie in ps output before it was cleaned up, or does it stay there indefinitely?

Comment: @thatotherguy - it is permanently stuck in that state. The script is actually started by `systemd` which is why it appears to be running as `root`

Comment: Does `do_something_that_includes_sleep` sometimes sleep for 0 seconds?  It feels like you're in a spin loop and the delay is not happening.

Comment: @WilliamPursell -  `do_something_that_includes_sleep` is actually sleeping for about 1 minute. Specifically, that function calls `iostat -y -c -d -k -o JSON -p -t 60 1`

Comment: Even with a sleep of 0 seconds, bash should be cleaning up its child processes. I would attach `strace` and see what it's up to, and if that shows it stuck in userspace then `gdb` on a debug build.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing that could happen with process substitution, not command substitution.

Comment: @Barmar - Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Process substitution doesn't wait for the process to exit, since it could run forever, e.g. `grep foo <(tail -f filename)`. So if the process exits, it might become a zombie (but maybe there's a `SIGCHLD` handler that reaps it). But this shouldn't happen with command substitution, it has to wait for it to finish so it can substitute the result into the command line.

Comment: `my_script` and `date` processes are 6 days apart, what happened in those 6 days ?

Comment: @Philippe - `my_script` is started once and then it runs forever in a loop. Therefore, it's expected that `date` would have a much later PID start date

Comment: We know that. You said `do_something_that_includes_sleep is actually sleeping for about 1 minute`, does that mean `date` runs roughly once every minute ? And at the end of six days, it ran and somehow became zombie ?

Comment: @Philippe - Correct. `date` should run once a minute. And after 6 days, it ran and became a zombie

Comment: `my_script---my_script---date` seems strange. According your `while` loop, you should have `my_script---date` with only one `my_script`.

Comment: @Philippe - You are correct. I was oversimplifying. The actual script has a `flock` around the `while` loop. That's where the second `my_script` PID comes from.

Answer (score 2):

After much hair pulling, and several additional failure instances which were investigated with GDB, I now have an answer. There is nothing wrong with the Bash script itself. The problem is the Bash version. What I didn't mention originally is that this problem was only seen when running on Debian Stretch which has Bash version 4.4.11 (from 4.4-5 DEB package). This version has a known bug that was reported back in 2017 and has since been fixed, which explains why my other test systems that are running newer OS's didn't see the same failure.

Original bug report - https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-02/msg00025.html

There was also a second bug which explicitly documents the 100% CPU utilization waiting for a zombie child at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-03/msg00141.html but that ultimately ties back to the original bug report.